# Where should I insert redux provider tag in a powerapp component platform app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, powerapps-modeldriven

In a typical regular react app with redux,  is wrapping app tag like this (in index.ts):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But in a PCF application I don't have any app tag, but several independent react components in their own containers, something like that (in index.ts):

```
public updateView(context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>): void
{
    ...
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Main, this.props),this.containerMain);
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(PanelButtons, this.props),this.containerAside);
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(PanelAux, this.props),this.containerAux);
    ...
}
```

Where should I insert the provider to wrapping the entire application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably in all of those calls if anything in their respective trees required Redux.
You are aware that you could rename the file to `.tsx` and just use
`<Main {...this.props} />` instead of `React.createElement(Main, this.props)`?

That would make the wrapping easier to read ;)

Comment: I cannot use a tsx as index, index.ts is mandatory in this kind of component for Powerapps Component Framework.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then you would write `React.createElement(Provider, { store },
    React.createElement(Main, this.props))`